# Texlive package manager in Ubuntu 10.4

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, texlive

There is no texlive package manager in Ubuntu 10.4 even if the version of texlive is 2009. Is there some package which should be installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tlmgr is unavailable in package managers because using it to update TeX packages could potentially break future updates through apt. See [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/591140) and [this](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/11449/). One possible solution is to get tlmgr to manage packages installed in TEXMFHOME but there's still work to be done on that front.